# Zoom in DevExpress Image Gallary

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, devexpress

How can I add a **zoom** feature to **DevExpress Image Gallary** control?

Comment: What do you want to zoom? When? Waht have you tried so far?

Comment: hi,my office document uplead in server jpeg format "text document" i want when user check the "text document" can zoom and the text clearly see!tnx marko please answer and help me

Answer (score 0):

You can simply open the image in PictureEdit control and zoom it there.